# ExecutionException thrown but without a cause

Tags: java, exception, executorservice, futuretask

I have a futures task that is doing some I/O operations over the socket to a server. When I use the `get()` method of the task to retrieve the result, I am getting `ExecutionException`, but with no cause i.e. `getCause()` returns `null`. In what scenario does this happen? I mean, I'm getting this exception since the task threw some exception right , but how can it go missing?

Comment: could it be that the causing exception is thrown on the server and class of the exception is not known on client?

Comment: 2) are both e.getCause() and e.getMessage() null/empty?

Comment: 3) one more possible cause? : http://thushw.blogspot.com/2010/07/beware-of-noclassdeffounderror-in.html

Comment: 1 -> i can say that the call didnt go to the server from the server logs .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
throw null;
```

is legal in Java, but I've never seen that in the wild.